Angular SwitchMap not trigger when refreshing token on interceptor
I have implemented a refresh token process in JwtInterceptor . When the accessToken has expired and return a 401 error, the Interceptor does not run the refreshingToken() function
This is my JwtInterceptor and refreshingToken function
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpErrorResponse,
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { from, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class JwtInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    const currentUserJwt = localStorage.getItem('pmsUserJwt');
    if (currentUserJwt) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUserJwt}`,
        },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (error.status === 401) {
          return from(this.authService.tryRefreshingTokens(currentUserJwt)).pipe(
            switchMap((success) => {
              if (success) {
                const newToken = localStorage.getItem('pmsUserJwt');
                request = request.clone({
                  setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${newToken}`,
                  },
                });
                return next.handle(request);
              }
            })
          );
        }
        return throwError(error);
      })
    );
  }
}

async tryRefreshingTokens(token: string): Promise {
const refreshTokens = localStorage.getItem('refreshToken');
if (!token || !refreshTokens) {
  console.log('Token or refresh token is missing.');
  return false;
}

const credentials = JSON.stringify({ accessToken: token, refreshToken: refreshTokens });

try {
  const refreshRes = await new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http
      .post<any>(`${this.API_URL.GENERAL}/${this.accountUrl}/refresh-token`, credentials, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => resolve(res),
        error: (err) => {
          console.error('Token refresh error:', err);
          reject(err);
        },
      });
  });

  if (refreshRes && refreshRes.data) {
    localStorage.setItem('pmsUserJwt', refreshRes.data.jwToken);
    localStorage.setItem('refreshToken', refreshRes.data.refreshToken);
    this.currentUserJwtSubject.next(refreshRes.data.jwToken);

    const user = this.parseJwt(refreshRes.data.jwToken);
    this.currentUserSubject.next(user);

    console.log('Tokens refreshed successfully');
    return true;
  } else {
    console.log('Refresh response is invalid.');
    return false;
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Exception during token refresh:', error);
  return false;
}

}
